# a problems about using C++ struct

Tags: c++

```
enum Attributes{ Branch, Node };

struct Node{
  Attributes att = Attributes::Node;

  char ch = '\0';

  unsigned int frequency = 0;

  Node* NextRightNode = nullptr;
  Node* NextLeftNode = nullptr;
};

const Node& operator=(Node& a, Node& b){
  if(b.att == Attributes::Node){
    a.att = Attributes::Node;
    a.ch = b.ch;
    a.frequency = b.frequency;

    a.NextLeftNode = nullptr;
    a.NextRightNode = nullptr;
  }else if(b.att == Attributes::Branch){
    a.att = Attributes::Branch;
    a.ch = '\0';
    a.frequency = 0;

    if(b.NextLeftNode != nullptr){
      *a.NextLeftNode = *b.NextLeftNode;
    }else{
      a.NextLeftNode = nullptr
        }

    if(b.NextRightNode != nullptr){
      *a.NextRightNode = *b.NextRightNode;
    }else{
      a.NextRightNode = nullptr
    }
  }

  return a;
}
```

I try to use g++.exe to compiler this code.
and it shows up this

```
fortry.cpp:14:7: error: 'Node' does not name a type
const Node& operator=(Node& a, Node& b){
      ^~~~
```

can someone tell me why it says Node does not name a type, please?

Comment: Use `enum class`

Comment: Is this the only error that the compiler gives you?  It looks like you have a naming conflict between the `enum` value `Attributes::Node` and the `struct` `Node`

Comment: did you try add "typedef" before word struct?

Comment: And assignment must be a member function.

Comment: @darvark: typedef is only relevant for structs in C, not in C++

Answer (score 1):

Unscoped enums (i.e. `enum` as opposed to `enum struct/class`) do not have their own scope.  Therefore, the value `Node` specified in `Attributes` is in the same scope as the class definition `Node`.  This ambiguity caused your compilation error.  If you replace your `enum` with `enum struct` or `enum class`, the value`Node` will be in the `Attributes` namespace, and therefore no conflict.

Comment: thanks, I change enum to enum class and the compilers don't show this error again.